# Как узнать предыдущее исключение в windbg?

Tags: c++, windows, исключения, windbg

Есть kernel dump **x64** в момент (2).

```
int* TouchMe = {};

void test_func()
{
    __try {
        *TouchMe = 1;   // (1)
    }
    __except (1) {
        *TouchMe = 2;   // (2)
    }
}
```

Кто-нибудь занет, есть ли возможность в этом дампе увидеть информацию об исключении в момент (1)?

Судя по моим тестам, windows использует одно и то же место на стеке для хранения context record и exception record в пределах одной функции. Т.е. исключение в момент (2) перезатирает инфу об исключении в момент (1).

Comment: В общем, податачился через virtualkd и поймал первое исключение.